# MainViewController pushViewController:animated:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1459e980

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, apple-push-notifications

I'm trying to add a functionality to open a specific view controller on opening the notification on my iOS app. As I am new to iOS, I have a few doubts.

I have written the backend, which sends the promo id as a custom parameter. I am able receive the JSON object on XCode, read the ID as a NSString.

Now, I want to open the PromotionDetailViewController with the promotion id as the parameter.

What I have done up to now is,

```
    PromotionDetailViewController *pVC = [[PromotionDetailViewController alloc] initWithPromotionID:promo_id[@"promo_id"]];
    [(UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController pushViewController:pVC animated:YES];

    [(UINavigationController *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController popViewControllerAnimated:YES ];
```

I am able to receive and read the promo ID in the AppDelegate.m file.
When I run the above code, I get the below error.

> MainViewController pushViewController:animated:]: unrecognized
>   selector sent to instance 0x1459e980

Any help in the right direction is great! I do php and android, but Obj-C is quite different!

**UPDATE**
Changed the code to this:

```
    PromotionDetailViewController *pvc = [[PromotionDetailViewController alloc] initWithPromotionID:promo_id[@"promo_id"]];
    UINavigationController *promoNav =
    [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:pvc];
    self.window.rootViewController = promoNav;
```

Now the API call is successful, I am able to see the correct NAV bar, but the app crashes due to the below error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason:
>   '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty
>   array'

Answer (score 0):

(UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController it seems that is not a UINavigationController.

To get the correct NavigationController you can do self.navigationController if 'self' is already a child controller of the navigation one.

In obj-c Unrecognized selector means that you are sending a message to an object that does not respond to that, since you are casting it manually with parenthesis, the compiler doesn't complain and thinks is actually a NavgiationController, but isn't.